# multiple checkbox function change in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I have an html which contains dynamically created tables. Im adding checkbox for each rows, as follows

```
    <table style="width: 100%" id="client_site_data" class="display">
        <caption>Client Site Info</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Set to Processing</th>
                <th>Sites</th>
                <th>Machines</th>
                <th>ProcessingState</th>
                <th>Last Updated</th>
                <th>Reset the Processing</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

....

$.each(data, function(id, value) {
                        rows.push('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox" value="'+value.site+':'+value.client+'\'"></td><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + value.machine
                                + '</td><td>' + value.state + '</td><td>'
                                + value.date_processed + '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="resetSite(\''+ value.site+'\',\''+value.client+'\')">Reset</td></tr>');
                    });
```

Im trying to POST the value using ajax to my backend service(which is python)

```
$("#chkbox").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var res = value.split(":");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/cache/setProcessing?site="+res[0]+"&client="+res[1],
                /*data: {
                        chkbox: value 
                },*/
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    alert('included for processing ');                 
                },
                error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Failed. Error : "
                            + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

But when i check the checkboxes in my table nothing happens. Means it is not calling my javascript function.

What im doing wrong? 
Also, if i select multiple rows at once, this logic is right/will work?

Edit:

I want to select multiple checkboxes.
So in my function I do like;

> ```
> $(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {
>           var sites = [];
>           var value = $(this).val();
>           var res = value.split(":");
>           $.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){            
>               sites.push(res[0]);
>             });
>           alert("sites are: " + sites.join(", "));
> ```
>
> });

But same site is repeated multiple times.

My modified html is like;

> ```
> $.each(data, function(id, value) {
>                       rows.push('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="chkbox" name="chkbox"
> ```
>
> value="'+value.site+':'+value.client+'">' + id + ''
>   + value.machine
>                                     + '' + value.state + ''
>                                     + value.date_processed + 'Reset');
>                         });

How can I get different sites for my checkboxes?

Comment: `$(document).on('change','#chkbox',function () {`. I would suggest to use class too instead of id or create a dynamic id for each of the checkbox.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have `id="chkbox"` in each row of the table.

Comment: @Barmer in this what will be the suitable option?

Comment: @ShadowFiend thanks that is calling my function now. Should I change ID when I dynamically create table?

Comment: @Ratha in this case i would suggest to use class that is only specifc for this checkbox.. then just use the this to get the value.. this checkboxes must have the same class..

Comment: @ShadowFiend any example ?

Comment: @Ratha `<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="chkbox" >` then the jquery will be `$(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {`

Comment: @ShadowFiend thanks..If i use class attribute should i use html form?.Or my current setup will work?

Comment: @Ratha your current setup will work.

Comment: @ShadowFiend thank you

Comment: @ShadowFiend i tried to select multiple rows at once. In my jquery  i tried like this, but it repeats same site multiple time $(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {
   var sites = [];
      var value = $(this).val();
      var res = value.split(":");
      $.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){            
        sites.push(res[0]);
            });
      alert("sites are: " + sites.join(", "));

Comment: @ShadowFiend I have provided detailed code block in my edited question

Comment: @Ratha post another question in the site.. so others and I can look at it..

Comment: @ShadowFiend done . here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822270/how-can-i-select-multiple-checkboxes-at-once