# How can I select multiple checkboxes at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table which is created dynamically. Im adding check box for each row.

```
$.each(data, function(id, value) {
  rows.push('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  autocomplete="off" class="chkbox" name="chkbox" value="'+value.site+':'+value.client+'"></td><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + value.machine + '</td><td>' + value.state + '</td><td>' + value.date_processed + '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="resetSite(\''+ value.site+'\',\''+value.client+'\')">Reset</td></tr>');
});
```

I want to select multiple rows at once and need to POST the values to my backend service.
Currently my JavaScript function is like;

```
$(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {
  var sites = [];
  var value = $(this).val();
  var res = value.split(":");
  $.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){            
    sites.push(res[0]);
  });
  alert("sites are: " + sites.join(", "));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/cache/setProcessing?site="+res[0]+"&client="+res[1],
    /*data: {
      chkbox: value 
    },*/
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Failed. Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

in the above function my alert box shows same site multiple times if I selecet more than one row.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: i think the problem is this `sites.push(res[0]);` so it only push the value of the `res[0]` all the time..

Comment: what is this res[0]? so u always push the same value all the time

Comment: @ShadowFiend no, the res contains joined value of "+value.site+':'+value.client". SO I split and get the first array[0] value

Comment: @Se0ng11 No, the res contains joined value of "+value.site+':'+value.client". SO I split and get the first array[0] value –

Comment: @Ratha ahh ok.. how about you put variable res and value inside the each function?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Yes I tried  var value too. but it contains same thing repeated. Is this because, I have defined id/class/name same for all rows?

Comment: @Ratha have you tried both inside? not just the value but also the variable res inside the each function? Something like `$.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){   
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    var res = value.split(":");         
                    sites.push(res[0]);
                });`

Comment: @ShadowFiend Thanks a lot ..That works.

Comment: @Ratha I'm glad I was able to help.. I will make an answer for it with the explanation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
$(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {
  var sites = [];
  var value = $(this).val();
  var res = value.split(":");
  $.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){            
    sites.push(res[0]);
  });
  alert("sites are: " + sites.join(", "));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/cache/setProcessing?site="+res[0]+"&client="+res[1],
    /*data: {
      chkbox: value 
    },*/
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Failed. Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

cor·re·spond·ing

```
$(document).on('change','.chkbox',function () {
  var sites = [];
  $.each($("input[class='chkbox']:checked"), function(){    
    var value = $(this).val(); // must me be inside the each
    var res = value.split(":");   // must me be inside the each     
    sites.push(res[0]);
  });
  alert("sites are: " + sites.join(", "));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/cache/setProcessing?site="+res[0]+"&client="+res[1],
    /*data: {
      chkbox: value 
    },*/
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Failed. Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Because in the previous code it only gets the value of the current checkbox you've clicked.

So you must put the `value` and `res` inside the `each function` to know all checkboxes that have been checked and get there corresponding value..

Comment: Here How can I change the Ajax call?Now it calls backend each and every time. I want to call it once the checkbox process is over

Comment: @Ratha what do you mean by *checkbox process is over*?

Comment: sorry my bad..this is oK for my requirement. I thought to ask, after selecting multiple rows, i want to POST that site[] to the backend service

Comment: can you explain it clearly? if the user finished checking the checkboxes then call ajax? like that?

Comment: Yes..That is what I wanted..May be i can put a button or something?